# Unresolved import: there is no `atan` in `std::num`

Tags: rust

I'm building examples from the Rust tutorial. When I try to compile this example:

```
use std::float;
use std::num::atan;
fn angle(vector: (float, float)) -> float {
    let pi = float::consts::pi;
    match vector {
      (0f, y) if y < 0f => 1.5 * pi,
      (0f, y) => 0.5 * pi,
      (x, y) => atan(y / x)
    }
}
```

I get the titular error. I'm compiling with `rust build Test.rs`. Why can't the compiler find `std::num::atan`?

Comment: Which version of rust are you using? 0.7? 0.8-pre?

Comment: I'm using 0.7. I'm also on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `atan` is not a member of `std::num` because it's defined as part of an `impl`. The following will work, however:

```
use std::float;

fn angle(vector: (float, float)) -> float {
    let pi = float::consts::pi;
    match vector {
      (0f, y) if y < 0f => 1.5 * pi,
      (0f, y) => 0.5 * pi,
      (x, y) => (y / x).atan()
    }
}
```

This is because `atan` is a member of `Trigonometric` which `float` implements.

The reason for this decision, I believe, is that there is no overloading in Rust, so in order for a function name to be applied to multiple concrete types, it has to be part of a Trait. In this case, `Trigonometric` is a numeric trait that allows multiple implementations of the methods `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, etc for `int`, `float`, `f64`, etc.

Comment: Is the tutorial out of date? Also, where is the best place to ask Rust questions?

Comment: Rust is still in active development (major version < 1) so there is a lot of code/doc churn and things aren't always right. It's also possible that you saw an outdated doc (I've accidentally read 0.2 docs). Where did you see the documentation for this?

Comment: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial.html#control-structures, the example using the offending import.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the docs. I've submitted a pull request to the main branch: https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/8117

Comment: Sorry, it looks like going forward in 0.8 there is a function named `atan` in `std::num`, but it must not be implemented in 0.7.

Comment: @Meta, the best places to ask questions are here, [#rust IRC](http://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23rust) and/or [the mailing list](https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/rust-dev). (#rust will often get you answers in seconds/minutes.)

Comment: @dbaupp Thanks for the info. I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to ask questions on the mailing list or not, and didn't know about the IRC.